# sed mongodb connection string copying multiple times in env variable through github action

Tags: command-line, scripts, application-development, sed

this is command which i run in github action its copying into .env.production file

```
sed -i "s#DB_URI=.*$#DB_URI=mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery#"
```

And this is error/job build status which shows multiples copying

```
DB_URI=***db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=trueDB_URI=***db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxx.com/webapp?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discoveryauthSource=adminDB_URI=***db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxx.com/webapp?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discoveryreplicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery
```

Plse let me how i can solve this

Comment: Try `echo sed -i "s#DB_URI=.*$#DB_URI=mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery#"` to see if what you get is what you expect.

Comment: i got this sed -i "s#DB_URI=.*$#DB_URI=mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery#"

Comment: Really? With the quotes and all?

Comment: yes i got response

Comment: Then it looks like you're not using Ubuntu in your action, so voting to close.

Comment: hello im using ubuntu agent in my action where thing is working but only DB_URI is copying multiples time through sed -i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape a few characters, and your command will work as the following:

```bash
sed -i 's#^DB_URI=.*$#DB_URI=mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=true\&authSource=admin\&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery#'
```

## Input test.txt

```
ABC=abc
DB_URI=Hello
LATER=abc
# comment
// comment
```

## Output test.txt

```
ABC=abc
DB_URI=mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery-f417ebf8.mongo.xxxxxxxxx.com/webapp_test?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-sfo3-api-discovery
LATER=abc
# comment
// comment
```

## Analysis

- The double quotes were causing bash to expand the `$#` to 0 or something. Stop that expansion with single quotes. Or else sed will crash with `` sed: -e expression #1, char 187: unterminated `s' command ``
- Add a `^` start anchor to stop one kind of duplication. EDIT: This doesn't seem to be necessary, but it's faster and more reliable
- Escape the `&` symbols to become `\&` so that sed doesn't expand them. According to `man sed`:

> The replacement may contain the special character & to refer  to that portion of the pattern space which matched